# Sinch Verification Fails for Android 9.0 OS

Tags: android, sinch, android-9.0-pie, android-sinch-api, sinch-verification

I am using Sinch Flash Call Verification SDK for android and it worked fine until I updated my OS to Android 9 on my Google Pixel Device. Now the verification is not happening.

The following happens: On invoking verification API, I receive a flash call on my device. However, after receiving the flash call, the verification fails.

On debugging, I got the following Logs:

> CallBroadcastReceiver: Exception while hanging up verification call:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission required.
>   {sinch_env: verificationapi-v1.sinch.com

Answer (score -2):

The version of the Sinch Verification SDK you're using didn't support Android 9, since Android 9 support was introduced in Sinch Verification SDK 1.5.3 (released late October 2018). Download the latest SDK and try again (https://www.sinch.com/downloads/).